# WebSphere MQ/MQSeries - Possible to send a message to multiple queues with single call?

Tags: oracle, message-queue, ibm-mq

I'm queuing messages to a WebSphere MQ queue (NB: A point-to-point queue -- not a topic) using a stored procedure in my Oracle database. Is there a way to publish each message to multiple queues with a single call? What I would like is to find a solution that would incur zero additional latency on my database compared to sending the message to a single queue.

Solutions that involve changing my WebSphere MQ settings are certainly welcome! What I had in mind was somehow creating a "clone" queue that got all the same messages as the original one, but I've been unable to locate anything like this in the documentation.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: No idea how to do what you want, but I would be interested in how you write to an MQ using a stored proc - is it a Java stored proc or a pure PLSQL?

Answer (score 2):

With WMQ v7 you can do this easily and with administration only.  You would create a topic object and then an alias over the topic.  The Oracle app writes to the alias and does not know that it is actually publishing.

Meanwhile, you make two administrative subscriptions on the topic so that publications are delivered to your two destination queues.  The apps consuming them have no idea that the messages were published as opposed to delivered through point-to-point queues.

If you are not familiar with the new WMQ v7 features, take a look at the [Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp).  In particular, the "What's New in V7" section and the sections on Pub/Sub.

Comment: From 10 years ago and maybe I'll you use this today!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using "Distribution Lists" in WebsphereMQ.  These have to be configured on your queue manager.

Take a look at the [Wesbphere MQ Application Programming Guide](http://www-05.ibm.com/e-business/linkweb/publications/servlet/pbi.wss?CTY=US&FNC=SRX&PBL=SC34-6595-00#) for more info.